# How to display a web page by CefSharp.Wpf browser control with local file resources

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I'am trying to use the CefSharp.Wpf NuGet package (v79.1.360) to display a simple html web page from disk.

The page has dependencies to local files (javascript, css, etc. ...) in a different directory than the page itself.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///G:/AngularJS/Framework/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyApp.css">

    <script src="file:///G:/AngularJS/Framework/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file:///G:/AngularJS/Framework/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file:///G:/AngularJS/Framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="MyApp.js"></script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
            <p class="font-weight-bold">Select address</p>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-primary">
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Code</th>
                        <th scope="col">City</th>
                        <th scope="col">Street</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="address in Model.AddressList"
                        ng-click="Model.PickRow(address)"
                        ng-style="{'background-color': address.Background}">
                        <td>{{address.Id}}</td>
                        <td>{{address.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{address.PostalCode}}</td>
                        <td>{{address.City}}</td>
                        <td>{{address.Street}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

*I'm able to display the page on a chromium based web browser (Firefox) with modified settings:
security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy false*

**-> Firefox isn't a chromium based web browser, so I tested it with google chrome and it worked too.**

On my web research I found this post related to the issue (unfortunately this post is from 2014):

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/572

So I tried to set the browser settings for the cef sharp control:

```html
<Window x:Class="WebControl.MyWebBrowser"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cefSharpCore="clr-namespace:CefSharp;assembly=CefSharp.Core"
        xmlns:cefSharpWpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <cefSharpWpf:ChromiumWebBrowser>
            <cefSharpWpf:ChromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings>
                <cefSharpCore:BrowserSettings WebSecurity="Disabled"
                                              FileAccessFromFileUrls="Enabled"
                                              UniversalAccessFromFileUrls="Enabled"/>
            </cefSharpWpf:ChromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings>
        </cefSharpWpf:ChromiumWebBrowser>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But this doesn't work. I also tried to set the settings in the code behind file without success.

Long story short:

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atzSA.png)
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7sVO.png)

If someone has a solution please let me know.

Thanks in advance for reading the post :-)

Comment: Firefox isn't a chromium browser. Have you confirmed that it works in Chrome? As per https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#file-uri-file I'd strongly discouraged anyone from using the File scheme. The recommended approach is https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#scheme-handler

Comment: Yes you're right: Firefox isn't chromium based, my fault :-) I tested it with google chrome and it worked like a charm. Because you discourage anyone from using file scheme I'll try the scheme handler way. Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you can move your files around you can use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_SchemeHandler_FolderSchemeHandlerFactory.htm

Comment: @HeikoR hi, i am trying to use cefsharp with wpf but i have problem with the use of local files, i see you have a complete sample wich is ok, could you share it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to amaitland for leading me to the right direction:

*I strongly advise against using file:/// when loading from local disk. Different security restrictions apply and there are many limitations. I'd suggest using a Scheme handler or implementing your own IResourceRequestHandlerFactory. (Loading a data: encoded URI is also pretty handy, specially for the OffScreen project).
If you choose to ignore this advice you'll have to resolve any issues you have using file:/// yourself. ceforum is the best resource.*

Copied from: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#file-uri-file

The solution is to create a custom scheme handler:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#scheme-handler

1) I addeded angular, bootstrap and jquery files as resources to my visual studio project.

2) I created DiskSchemeHandlerFactory.cs:

```
public class DiskSchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
{
    private static readonly string _SchemeName = "disk";
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> _ResourceDictionary;


    public string SchemeName
    {
        get { return _SchemeName; }
    }


    static DiskSchemeHandlerFactory()
    {
        _ResourceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "/angular.min.js", Properties.Resources.angular_min },
            { "/angular.min.js.map", Properties.Resources.angular_min_js },
            { "/bootstrap.min.js", Properties.Resources.bootstrap_min1 },
            { "/bootstrap.min.css", Properties.Resources.bootstrap_min },
            { "/jquery.min.js", Properties.Resources.jquery_min }
        };
    }


    public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
    {
        //Notes:
        // - The 'host' portion is entirely ignored by this scheme handler.
        // - If you register a ISchemeHandlerFactory for http/https schemes you should also specify a domain name
        // - Avoid doing lots of processing in this method as it will affect performance.
        // - Uses the Default ResourceHandler implementation

        var uri = new Uri(request.Url);
        var fileName = uri.AbsolutePath;

        string resource;
        if (_ResourceDictionary.TryGetValue(fileName, out resource) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(resource))
        {
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            return ResourceHandler.FromString(resource, fileExtension);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

3) I modified the static constructor of MyWebBrowser.xaml.cs:

```
    static MyWebBrowser()
    {
        if (Cef.IsInitialized == false)
        {
            var diskSchemeHandlerFactory = new DiskSchemeHandlerFactory();

            var settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme()
            {
                SchemeName = diskSchemeHandlerFactory.SchemeName,
                SchemeHandlerFactory = diskSchemeHandlerFactory
            });

            Cef.Initialize(settings);
        }
    }
```

4) Finally I changed the file paths of the html page:

```
<script src="disk://angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="disk://jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="disk://bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe I modify it to work with full file paths too. With this solution I have to compile my project each time I want to use another file...

Comment: it works. N.B return ResourceHandler.FromString(resource, fileExtension) is now ResourceHandler.FromString(resource, mimeType: Cef.GetMimeType(Path.GetExtension(fileName))). thanks